# replace all matches with different text in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have list of links in a different text file (one link per line)

```
links[0] = "link 1"

links[1] = "link 2"

links[2] = "link 3"

links[3] = "link 4"
```

I want to add in all the links between `" "` and `links[x]` should auto increment or if there is a random (unique) number between " [] "  that will also work.

Comment: When you say "different file". what does the other file look like? Can you show what you'd like the output to look like? Are programs other than notepad++ an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Notepad++, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636539/lines-number-using-regex-in-notepad

Also, a tiny shell script could do this:

```
i=0; for l in $(<inputfile); do echo 'links['$i'] = "$l"'; i=$(($i++)); done
```